# Quitar autocompletado al vaciar el input JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eventos, input, innerhtml

Para poder formular una pregunta correctamente en Stack overflow tengo que elegir una serie de etiquetas que la página me recomienda cuando empiezo a escribir en el **input para añadir etiquetas**, si yo borro en su totalidad el **texto del input** la página reconoce ese **input** como vacío y se desaparecen automáticamente las **etiquetas recomendadas para autocompletar**, independientemente de la forma en la que se borre el **texto del input** ósea seleccionando todo el texto con el ratón y suprimiéndolo con la tecla de **retroceder** o posicionándome al final del texto y mantener presionada la tecla de retroceder hasta borrar el texto en su totalidad, la lista de etiquetas recomendadas siempre desaparece cuando el **input se vacía**.

Esta misma funcionalidad la quiero implementar en mi proyecto pero tengo problemas y evidentemente algo estoy haciendo mal pero ¿no se que será? **imagen de mi proyecto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si miramos la imagen en la consola se puede ver que he escrito un texto en el **input** y lo he borrado con la tecla de **retroceder** hasta vaciarlo, pero la lista de etiquetas recomendadas no se borra.
**código JavaScript:**

```
function recomendedTagList() {
    const inputValue = inputAddTags.value.trim();
    console.log(inputValue);
    if (inputValue !== "") {//Condición que comprueba que el input no esta vacio

        //Al entrar en esta condición hace la petición http para buscar
        //en la base de datos de etiquetas las etiquetas que coincidan con lo que el 
        //usuario esta escribiendo:

        fetch("http://localhost/proyecto-laravel/public/get_tags", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ input: inputValue }),
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error("Error en la petición");
                }
            })
            .then((data) => {
                tagListResponse.innerHTML = "";

                //Si todo ha salido bien se crean las etiquetas html para mostrar la lista
                //de etiquetas valga la redundancia:

                if (data && data.data && data.data.length > 0) {
                    const tags = data.data;
                    const tagList = document.createElement("div");

                    tags.forEach((tag) => {
                        const listItem = document.createElement("div");
                        listItem.textContent = tag.tags;
                        tagList.appendChild(listItem);
                    });

                    tagListResponse.appendChild(tagList);
                } else {
                    tagListResponse.textContent = "No se encontraron etiquetas";
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });
    } else {

        //Bloque que confirma que el input esta vacio o se ha vaciado y posteriormente "se supone 
        //se debe de limpiar la lista de etiquetas" 

        console.log("vaciado")
        tagListResponse.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
//Aqui se hace uso del método:
inputAddTags.addEventListener("input", recomendedTagList);
```

**Trozo de código html necesario para entender la pregunta:**

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" class="form-group">
  <div class="col">
   <p class="remaining-tags-count"><span id="tagsCount">_</span> Etiquetas restantes</p>
    <ul id="AddedTags">
      <input id="addTags" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    </ul>
  </div>
 <span id="tagListResponse" class="d-flex flex-wrap"></span>
</form>
```

Basicamente me gustaria que independientemente de cual sea la forma de **vaciar el input** que prefiera el usuario la lista de etiquetas recomendadas desaparezca pero a pesar que que entra en el else que confirma que el input esta vació no parece que ejecute la acción de limpiar el tagListResponse.

Comment: Quiero añadir a mi pregunta algo mas, no quiero decir con mi pregunta que la lista de etiquetas no se borra cuando vacío el input con la tecla de retroceder, lo que quiero decir es que en algunas ocasiones no se borra cuando presiono retroceder y justo en el momento en que se ha vaciado completamente el input suelto la tecla y allí es cuando la lista no desaparece, es como un glitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que tu problema está en el `fetch`. Voy a simplificar tu código e inventar una función `FakeFetch` que simula el `fetch`

Se puede ver que no hay problema en el siguiente código

```js
async function FakeFetch(){
  return new Promise(r => r());
}

function recomendedTagList() {
    const inputValue = inputAddTags.value.trim();
    if (inputValue !== "") {
        FakeFetch().then((data) => {
               tagListResponse.innerHTML = "TAGS";
        });
    } else {
        console.log("vaciado")
        tagListResponse.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
//Aqui se hace uso del método:
inputAddTags.addEventListener("input", recomendedTagList);
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;" class="form-group">
  <div class="col">
   <p class="remaining-tags-count"><span id="tagsCount">_</span> Etiquetas restantes</p>
    <ul id="AddedTags">
      <input id="inputAddTags" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    </ul>
  </div>
 <span id="tagListResponse" class="d-flex flex-wrap"></span>
</form>
```

Pero ahora añadimos un pequeño `delay` que es natural en un `fetch`

```js
async function FakeFetch(){
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(()=>r(true), 100));
}

function recomendedTagList() {
    const inputValue = inputAddTags.value.trim();
    if (inputValue !== "") {
        FakeFetch().then((data) => {
               tagListResponse.innerHTML = "TAGS";
        });
    } else {
        console.log("vaciado")
        tagListResponse.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
//Aqui se hace uso del método:
inputAddTags.addEventListener("input", recomendedTagList);
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;" class="form-group">
  <div class="col">
   <p class="remaining-tags-count"><span id="tagsCount">_</span> Etiquetas restantes</p>
    <ul id="AddedTags">
      <input id="inputAddTags" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    </ul>
  </div>
 <span id="tagListResponse" class="d-flex flex-wrap"></span>
</form>
```

Si vas borrando lento funciona, pero si lo haces rápido aparece el hay error. Esto te pasa porque cuando mantienes presionado el backspace va consultado, llegado al anteúltimo realiza una solicitud `fetch` que tiene un `delay`, pero cuando borra el último no existe el fetch así que el `tagListResponse.innerHTML = "";` se ejecuta instantáneamente, pero luego de eso se resuelve el `fetch` anterior (que aun no se había resuelto) y pisa todo

La solución es abortar el `fetch` cuando el `input` ha cambiado, ya que todos los fetch pendientes pierden sentido cuando texto de entrada es otro.

Para esto puedes usar [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)

```js
let controller = new AbortController()
function recomendedTagList() {
    controller.abort();
    controller = new AbortController();
    
    const inputValue = inputAddTags.value.trim();
    if (inputValue !== "") {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',{
          signal: controller.signal, //<--- Agregar esto al fetch
        }).then((data) => {
               tagListResponse.innerHTML = "TAGS";
        });
    } else {
        console.log("vaciado")
        tagListResponse.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
//Aqui se hace uso del método:
inputAddTags.addEventListener("input", recomendedTagList);
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;" class="form-group">
  <div class="col">
   <p class="remaining-tags-count"><span id="tagsCount">_</span> Etiquetas restantes</p>
    <ul id="AddedTags">
      <input id="inputAddTags" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    </ul>
  </div>
 <span id="tagListResponse" class="d-flex flex-wrap"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Ya lo he probado y no solo no logra quitar la lista sino que me aparece por la consola este error varia veces:  Error: DOMException: The user aborted a request.

Comment: Muestra una imagen del código que tienes

Comment: @DaniBN Pero para clarificar, el código que te he puesto funciona, es cosa de presionar el botón ejecutar y probar, así que sospecho que tu problema está en como implementaste a tu código la respuesta. Luego la excepción salta al abortar, esto es así y queda señalado en lo más abajo de la documentación que te enlazado en la respuesta

Comment: Yussef ya me ha funcionado y he entendido en que estaba fallando muchas gracias, es que a mi con el tema de la asincronía me cuesta acostumbrarme, me borra la lista a pesar de la forma en la que borro el input porque el fetch que se resuelve al final se aborta entiendo, y el mensaje de error es en realidad el mensaje de que se ha abortado la petición y si quiero lo muestro y si no no.

Comment: @DaniBN Que bueno te haya funcionado finalmente. El tema de la sincronía a todos nos ha costado, es cosa de usarlo hasta acostumbrarse. Saludos y suerte en el proyecto

Answer (score -1):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema está en que estás usando una forma para añadir los *tags* (`appendChild`) y otra forma para decir que no hay coincidencias (`textContent`). Por lo cual, al no haber coincidencias, si ya tenías elementos añadidos previamente con `appendChild`, no serán removidos por `textContet`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es usar el mismo tipo de acción sobre el contenedor de *tags*, para asegurarte que realmente estás vaciando el elemento.

Si deseas usar sólo `textContent`, la solución podría verse así:

```js
const tags = [
  'javascript', 'java', '.net', 'mongodb', 'c++',
  'php', 'c#', 'c', 'cobol', 'html', 'css'
];

const noTagsMessage = 'No se encontraron etiquetas';

function recomendedTagList(event) {
  const inputValue = event.currentTarget.value.trim();
  if (inputValue) {
    const _tags = tags.filter(t => t.includes(inputValue));
    document.getElementById('tagListResponse').textContent = _tags.length
      ? _tags.join(', ')
      : noTagsMessage;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('tagListResponse').textContent = noTagsMessage;
  }
}


document.getElementById('addTags').addEventListener('input', recomendedTagList);
```

```html
<input id="addTags" autocomplete="off" type="text">
<br>
<span id="tagListResponse"></span>
```

Pero si deseas usar `appendChild` entonces el código podría verse así:

```js
const tags = [
  'javascript', 'java', '.net', 'mongodb', 'c++',
  'php', 'c#', 'c', 'cobol', 'html', 'css'
];



function recomendedTagList(event) {
  const inputValue = event.currentTarget.value.trim();
  if (inputValue) {
    const tagList = document.createElement('div');
    tagList.setAttribute('id', 'tagList');
    const _tags = tags.filter(t => t.includes(inputValue));
    if (_tags.length) {
      _tags.forEach(t => {
        const _t = document.createElement('div');
        _t.innerText = t;
        tagList.appendChild(_t);
      });
    }
    if (document.getElementById('tagList')) {
        document.getElementById('tagListResponse').removeChild(document.getElementById('tagList'));
      }
    document.getElementById('tagListResponse').appendChild(tagList);
  } else {
    if (document.getElementById('tagList')) {
        document.getElementById('tagListResponse').removeChild(document.getElementById('tagList'));
      }
  }
}


document.getElementById('addTags').addEventListener('input', recomendedTagList);
```

```html
<input id="addTags" autocomplete="off" type="text">
<br>
<span id="tagListResponse"></span>
```

En este segundo ejemplo, al crear la lista de *tags* la reemplazo, mediante el uso de [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild), consultando si dicho nodo existe (`if (document.getElementById('tagList')`). Luego, puedo añadir dicha lista, sea que esté vacía o llena.

En caso que el valor de `input` sea una cadena vacía, hago la misma verificación para saber si la lista es un nodo hijo de nuestro elemento `span`, si lo es, basta con removerlo para que desaparezca de la UI.

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que al parecer tu problema radica en la forma en que manejas la asíncronía de la petición `fetch`, vamos a emular esto usando el código anterior:

```js
function fetchTags(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const tags = [
      'javascript', 'java', '.net', 'mongodb', 'c++',
      'php', 'c#', 'c', 'cobol', 'html', 'css'
    ];
    const _tags = tags.filter(t => t.includes(value));
    setTimeout(() => resolve(_tags), 500);
  });
}


function recomendedTagList(event) {
  const inputValue = event.currentTarget.value.trim();
  if (inputValue) {
    fetchTags(inputValue).then(tags => {
      const tagList = document.createElement('div');
      tagList.setAttribute('id', 'tagList');
      if (tags.length) {
        tags.forEach(t => {
          const _t = document.createElement('div');
          _t.innerText = t;
          tagList.appendChild(_t);
        });
      }
      if (document.getElementById('tagList')) {
          document.getElementById('tagListResponse').removeChild(document.getElementById('tagList'));
      }
      if (document.getElementById('addTags').value === inputValue) {
        document.getElementById('tagListResponse').appendChild(tagList);
      };
    });
  } else {
    if (document.getElementById('tagList')) {
        document.getElementById('tagListResponse').removeChild(document.getElementById('tagList'));
      }
  }
}


document.getElementById('addTags').addEventListener('input', recomendedTagList);
```

```html
<input id="addTags" autocomplete="off" type="text">
<br>
<span id="tagListResponse"></span>
```

Basta que lo adaptes a tu llamada `fetch`. Toma en cuenta que he añadido el 'delay' adecuado para la llamada `fetch` y se ha añadido una guarda para evitar añadir la lista si el contenido del `input` es diferente del esperado.

Comment: Ya veo pero es que la lista de etiquetas se crea dentro de una petición http, si no existe valor en el input no se hace la petición y no se crean las etiquetas con sus id por eso es que en mi caso nunca va a entrar en esta condición: if (document.getElementById('tagList')) porque nunca se han creado

Comment: @DaniBN no veo cuál es el problema que se cree la lista en una petición `fetch`. Si el input estaba lleno y luego se vacía, sólo se verifica si la lista existe y si existe, se elimina.

Comment: Ok ya he visto donde estaba mi error, ya me fije porque no entraba en el if, pero la cosa es que la lista sigue sin borrarse.

Comment: Hola El Troll gracias por tu paciencia para responder a esta pregunta no quiero desanimar pero el comportamiento que tiene la aplicación con los cambios que me has planteado es el mismo, la lista se borra si borro el contenido del input pero si mantengo presionada la tecla de retroceder hasta borrar el texto no están entrando en este if (document.getElementById('tagList')) {}           dependiendo de como manipule el input algunas veces entra y otras no, es rarísimo pero por eso es que estoy formulando esta pregunta.

Comment: @DaniBN he editado la respuesta para mostrarte un flujo asíncrono. Date cuenta la forma en que estoy declarando los elementos, el orden de los mismos y el hecho de que los capturo del DOM en el momento en que voy a usarlos con `document.getElementById()`.